# homestead.rb:63:in `configure': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: vagrant

I followed how to install Laravel but after all when I entered "vagrant up" i get these errors:

```
C:/Users/Renz/code/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:63:in `configure':
undefined m ethod `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
   from C:/Users/Renz/code/Homestead/Vagrantfile:9:in `block in <top (requi red)>'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `each'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `each'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:614:in `new'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:614:in `vagrantfile'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:399:in `host'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:198:in `block in action_runner'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:386:in `hook'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:596:in `unload'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
   from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

I tried re-installing multiple times but still get the same error.

Please help, I really need to fix this now. Appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem and my issue was with the folders and sites configs in homestead.yaml, so perhaps you want to show us your file so we'll try to spot the issue...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to have a database added to your Homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code/testprogram
      to: /home/vagrant/testprogram

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/test/public

databases:
    - name: testprogram

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! The less obvious scenario occurs when one attempts to `vagrant up` as a user who lacks a `.homestead` directory with `Homestead.yaml` inside it. I'm surprised that something doesn't fail sooner with "The `.homestead` directory doesn't exist in your home directory, and if it does, it lacks a valid `Homestead.yaml` file that defines at least one database."

Comment: Just another note to be aware of - If your `.homestead` directory resides on a mapped network drive, be sure that your system still had that drive mapped.

I just ran into an issue where trying to `vagrant up` was failing with this error and unaware to myself at the time, the network drive where my `.homestead` was no longer mapped to my user. A quick and easy fix once I realized what had happened, so someone may be able to save some frustration by checking on that earlier!

Comment: or just remove databases block

Answer (score 2):

It happens when your Homestead.yamel file is like this

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code/testprogram
      to: /home/vagrant/testprogram

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/test/public
ports: < This line should be comment too<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
#   - send: 80
#     to: 80
```

if you comment that line or delete it the it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty familiar how initialization of the Homestead environment works on Windows, but this kind of error appears when you try to run the vagrant machine without initialize the environment before.

Just be sure you typed:

```
init.bat
```

Regards!